# Autocompletion results formatting with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, plugins

I am currently using [this autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions). It's pretty straightforward.  It accepts a URL, and then uses that data to perform an auto-complete.

This is my code to auto-complete it.

```
autocompleteurl = '/misc/autocomplete/?q='+$("#q").val()
$("#q").autocomplete(autocompleteurl, {multiple:true});
```

If someone types "apple", that `autocompleteurl` page will return this result:

```
apple store,applebees,apple.com,apple trailers,apple store locator,apple vacations,applebees menu,apple iphone,apple tablet,apple tv
```

However, for some reason, when I actually use this auto-complete, everything is junked together.  The plugin treats the entire page as a one big string, instead of separating the commas and treating them as individual items.

Can someone tell me what options I need to put in order to treat them as individual items? I've tried many options but none work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions)

> A value of "foo" would result in this
>   request url:
>   my_autocomplete_backend.php?q=foo&limit=10
>
> The result must return with one value
>   on each line. The result is presented
>   in the order the backend sends it.

From what you have posted it seems like you have it comma separated.

Comment: So, I have to separate it by <br/>?

Comment: echo "\n"; between the individual entries

Answer (score 0):

The plugin automatically adds the `q` to the querystring and uses the current value of the text box as the value.

This should be sufficient as long as you're returning the data in the correct format:

```
$("#q").autocomplete('/misc/autocomplete/', {multiple:true});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh.  However, for some reason, everytime I type a letter into the text box, it calls that autocomplete page, but with only ONE letter!? Instead of "a" then "ab" then "abc", it will call each letter individually. ?q=a&limit=10&timestamp=1257633995436  ?q=c&limit=10&timestamp=1257633995436   ?q=c&limit=10&timestamp=1257633995436

Answer (score 0):

@alex I'm getting quirky behavior too - for 2/3/4 alphabets.
See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#toptions .
If you set the minChars option to 2 or 3 it makes things more sane.
There's funny behavior when you have 5 results for "ab" and the same 5 results for "abc" - it does *nothing*, giving the *impression that it is not working*!
But it is working and I suspect it has to do with caching options.